# Software Center doesn't work as it should in Awesome WM

Tags: 12.04, software-center, awesome

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and Awesome window manager. When I run `software-center` I cannot install or remove software. I get the following warning:

```
softwarecenter.backend - WARNING - _on_trans_error: org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name':  ':1.105'}): org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages
```

It worked just fine outside Awesome wm. I searched on google/askubuntu and found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99442/software-center-install-button-doesnt-do-anything) post, which seemed to had the solution (`gksudo software-center & exit`).

Now I can install new software, but I can't view or search my installed software . The page just keeps showing the loading icon, but won't ever load. I don't get any warnings or errors.

Just to be clear, installing/removing/searching using synaptics/apt-get/dpkg works just fine.

Comment: The question, you mentioned, lists this behaviour as a bug. Please see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1045186

Comment: Since this is a bug, this question will probably be closed as off-topic, in accordance with [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) and [this policy](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/228/22949). Please note that you can run Software Center with sudo rather than PolicyKit as a workaround (as stated in comments in the bug report). The best way to do that is usually to press Alt+F2 and run `gksu software-center`.